# Parsing stops on null or []

Tags: parsing, null, jq

I have this filter working well but after a new use case where the property "p" can be null or a empty array [], the parser stop to evaluate the expression.

".p[]?.product.productId" the issue is here, when p is null or an empty array [].

When I have the p property like this, it works well. [{}] or [{"id":123}]

I'm breaking the filter in lines to make it easy to understand.

```
.p as $p 
| .p[]?.product.productId as $pa 
| .io[] 
| select(.product.productId == ($pa) or .description == "product description x") 
|  .product.productId as $pid 
|  {"offerId": .offerId, 
    "description": .description, 
    "required": 
       "($p[] | select(.product.productId == $pid) | .required)", 
    "applied": false, 
    "amount": (if .prices | length == 0 
       then 0 
       elif .prices[0].amount != null 
       then .prices[0].amount 
       else .prices[0].amountPercentage 
       end)}
```

Input:

```
{
   "p": null,
   "io": [{
     "offerId": 5593,
     "description": "product description x",
     "product": {
        "productId": 393,
        "description": "product description x 2",
        "type": "Insurance"
     },
     "prices": [
        {
           "amount": null,
           "amountPercentage": 4.13999987,
           "status": "On"
        }
     ]
  }]
}
```

All I want is to be able to ignore the P when it is null or [].

*I'm aware about this literal expression "($p[] | select(.product.productId == $pid) | .required)"

jqplay.org/s/wYwKUFM2XR

Regards

Comment: What should happen when `p` is `null`?

Comment: Also this expression is wrong `"required": "($p[] | select(.product.productId == $pid) | .required)"` it prints the literal value for the filter

Comment: I forgot to mention about it, I left literal to make the filter works but I need this logic as well. I'm expecting to get the filter work independently of p. The p has additional attributes that I can replace by a default value like false on that literal expression.

Comment: ok, but still, what should happen to `p` if it is null?

Comment: I just want to ignore the P if it is null, just it!

Comment: For now, I wrapped the expression with a if, if p==null then (expression without use the p variable) else (current expression) end

Answer (score 1):

1. E? is like `try E catch empty`, whereas what you seem to want is either `try E catch null` or perhaps`E? // null`
2. `.p[]?` is not the same as `.p?[]` or .p?[]?:

```
     $ jq -n '[] | .p[]?'
     jq: error (at <unknown>): Cannot index array with string "p"
     $ jq -n '[] | .p?[]'
     $
     $ jq -n '[] | .p?[]?'
     $
```

Specifically, `.p[]` is like `.p | (try .[] catch empty)`, so there is nothing to stop the `.p` from raising an exception.

You might like to consider using `try` explicitly:

```
$ jq -n '[] | try .p[] catch null'
$
```

Comment: Many thanks but I'm not getting any error, just doesn't work... Look at here https://jqplay.org/s/wYwKUFM2XR. Try to set any value on p like [{}] and it works.

Comment: See update. In future, it would be a good idea if you tried to follow the guidelines at [mcve] - notably, providing a *minimal* example and the expected result.